# Optaplanner input files

Tags: optaplanner

I am trying to use the Optaplanner for a business case that I have, which is about the VRP problem.  As I am not an expert programmer, I deal with the problem of imputing the information to the software.  The files in the example are .vrp files so I could not manage to find out how can I change them. I have my files in txt format but I cannot find a way how to use them. I hope that there is a easy way to maybe convert the txt files into vrp.

Thank you very much in advance.

Michail

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no magic program that takes an arbitrary formatted `txt` file and turns into the `vrp` format used by the example in OptaPlanner. The example is meant as a starting point for programmers, so they can customize to their business needs and put it in their business UI.

Note: OptaPlanner itself has no input/output formats. The OptaPlanner example VehicleRouting can load a file in the format vrp (or also xstream xml) in to it's VRP domain objects, but it also possible to write some code to load it from a database or something else.